# Elastic BeanStalk environment variable update fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

When I try to update the environment variables of my Elastic BeanStalk environment via the software configuration, the update fails and the environment is rolled back to the previous configuration (see image).

[image: events]

Does anyone know why this might happen? The strange thing is that whenever I deploy the full CodePipeline (GitHub -> build files on build server -> deploy to Elastic BeanStalk) the whole process succeeds. Only whenever I try to change the software configuration, the process fails.

It seems to go wrong somewhere in the CloudFormation stack:

[image]

I have never manually changed the stack, it was entirely constructed via a CodePipeline configuration.

Comment: That error in the second screenshot looks like the culprit - when you edit it manually are you missing out some variable that needs setting?

Comment: I will look into that. But what's weird is that I have never manually changed the stack, so I figured a syntax error of some sort would be unlikely. Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: I must say though that I am rather inexperienced with CloudFormation, especially since the whole deployment was setup via Elastic BeanStalk. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach the issue?

Comment: Might manually changing the name tag of an EC2 (which I did) have caused this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't do, as tags are only tags - normally easily reverted back by CloudFormation. If you go to the CloudFormation console itself, is there more info on the error? Under the Stack -> Events?

Comment: The error I posted (the `Fn::join` error) is everything I can see under Stack -> Events. Also, when I go to the stack template editor and validate the template, the validation succeeds. Which shouldn't happen if there is a syntax error, right?

Comment: It may not be a syntax error but something that is omitted when you run it manually. As in, a variable or parameter that is not being passed in, so is empty, so the join fails.

Comment: Okay so what I tried to do is create a Elastic BeanStalk environment completely from scratch. But as soon as I try to add a RDS database, I get this error: `Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-4p3iiqmssm-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: null`. Can't help but feel they are related... Also, reason null?

Comment: I have created a different thread for this issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/1093976/attaching-rds-database-to-elastic-beanstalk-fails-with-reason-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has resolved overnight, just like how it appeared. Was thus likely on the side of AWS.